How to avoid NetSuite record has been changed error?
I have developed scheduled script to create journal entry records for each invoice item. Now, I have created 2 functions.
First function, creates journal entries for all items on invoice records.
Second function, sets created journal entry record reference on invoice record's subslist.
Now I have added logic to reschedule script to avoid usage issue in first function.
If I create je and set craeted je on invoice line for 50 items batch and then reschedule the script in second function. In that case I have to save invoice record after every 50 items. I think it will error out as record has been changed. Please advice!
Please advice!
Below is pseudocode:
function execute()
{
    //Fetches data from saved search and create journal entries
    createjournals();
 
}
function createjournals()
{
    //create Journal entries
     journal.save
     if(remainingusage<100)
     {
     reschedulescript();
     }
     if(createdjearray.length>0)
     {
     updateinvoicelines();
     }
}
function updateinvoicelines()
{
    //set Journal entries references on invoice item line
    invoice.save();
}


If you are creating a journal on every invoice you might want to look at the GL Lines Plugin as an alternative.
If you create JEs in response to Invoices you may also have to adjust your JEs for every change, void and deletion of those invoices.
Note that there is nothing in your pseudo code to indicate what the issue might be. Generally those are caused by user event scripts or workflows that save the record in a before submit event handler or after submit handler that tries to update the context.newRecord value rather than loading updating and saving it.

When working with updateinvoicelines(), ensure you minimize the duration between loading and saving the record. Fetch the record, update only the necessary fields, and save it immediately.
Add error-handling logic to retry saving the record if it fails due to a "Record has been changed" error. This can be done with a try-catch block and a retry mechanism.
